# How would I serialize XML in a JSON string?

Tags: javascript

How would I serialize XML into a valid value in a JSON string?

Let's say I have this XML:

```
<root>
   <item label="hello's there" />
</root>
```

And I want to pass it with a JSON object / string like so:

```
var myJSON = "{'name':'dork','value':" + xml + "'}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a string create an object and pass it to the JSON.stringify method like so:

```
var object = {};
object.name = "dork";
object.xml = myXML;
var result = JSON.stringify(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON.stringify method to turn the string into a string literal in JSON format:

```
var myJSON = '{"name":"dork","value":' + JSON.stringify(xml) + '}';
```

Note that the quotation marks around the string is added by the `stringify` method.

Note also that the JSON syntax requires quotation marks (`"`) around identifiers and strings, apostrophes (`'`) are not valid.